# Get list of tables from SQLite in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Below code returns only the name of first table, how to get list of all available table names in existing **sqlite**?

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('path/to/mydb.sqlite');
db.serialize(function () {
    db.get("select name from sqlite_master where type='table'", function (err, table) {
        console.log(table);
    });
});
```

**Output**

```
{name: "meta"}
```

When opened in sqlite3 command-line

```
sqlite> .tables
downloads             meta                  urls
downloads_url_chains  segment_usage         visit_source
keyword_search_terms  segments              visits
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [get()'s doc](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databasegetsql-param--callback):

> Runs the SQL query with the specified parameters and calls the callback with **the first result row** afterwards.

You have to use [db.all()](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback):

```
db.serialize(function () {
    db.all("select name from sqlite_master where type='table'", function (err, tables) {
        console.log(tables);
    });
});
```

Or [db.each()](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete) if you want to call the callback for every row:

```
db.serialize(function () {
    db.each("select name from sqlite_master where type='table'", function (err, table) {
        console.log(table);
    });
});
```